# Start service once and forever untill it gets killed

Tags: android, service, lifecycle

A simple question, how to make a Service repeat at log cat console msg "hello", as long as the Service is living/is active? I've tried:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        Mano lopas = new Mano(this);
        lopas.Lopas();
        while(true) {
        Log.v("HAHA", "hello");
        }
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

But it never returns START_STICKY, actually it doesnt even build the project. I think im missing something about services? I start my service, in MainActivity in my application, like:

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Myclass.class));
```

And it runs only once without my while loop in my service. It says me something in Logcat and this is it. Morever, my service starts so many times as many times I re-open my application. How to make service start run once and "forever", I mean untill it gets killed by the system or user kills it.

Comment: "it doesn't even build the project" What error do you get?

Comment: "Unreachable code" near return statement since while(true) is in the middle.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you need to start another thread to run your loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, do not forget to register the `Service` in your Manifest.

This can be done by using

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".services.Paycan" />
```

Next is, that your Service (if its not an intentservice) run in the MainUI. If you create an endless loop make sure it's in a background thread, otherwise it will freeze the app.

You can do it using an `Asynctask`, a Thread which get created with `onStartCommand` and stopped in `onDestroy` or use an `IntentService` instead of a `Service`.

example:

```
public class yourTestClass extends Service {

    Thread testThread;
    boolean threadRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); 
        testThread = new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
          try {
            while(threadRunning) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Log.i("test", "....");
            }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
       } 
     };
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       threadRunning = true;
       testThread.start();
       return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        threadRunning = false;
    }
```

Comment: Will not I get second thread somewhere in memory when I re-enter my app since service is created in onCreate method, in MainActivity for example ?

Comment: This is why you have to start it in onStartCommand and end it in onDestroy. Create the Thread itself in onCreate().

Comment: Sorry I'm totally lost. I start a service in onCreate method. and I will get many threads if I create thread in onStartCommand? Thats why I have to start Service in onStartCommand without even starting a service?

Comment: No. You will create the Thread in onCreate (since this is called only 1 time. Reinitializing the Thread is not needed), start it in onStart(command) and end it in onDestroy.

Comment: `threadRunning` needs to be `volatile` or the worker thread may never stop.

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold thanks for time, explaining how and where and for example also. But how to stop the thread? I try testThread.stop(); in onDestroy method of my Service, but I get warning The method stop() from the type Thread is deprecated.

Comment: check the boolean threadRunning. Threads are not designed to cancel it  before it's loop has been looped. it will stop it when you've assigned false to the threadRunning.

Comment: Ye but will it also completely destroy the thread? because user maybe will kill my service via settings, and next time I will have already 3 threads intead of 2(main and thread that I created)

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold and I just tried the example, seems like it doesnt want to create a new thread and run my while loop.

Comment: This code will also crash with an `IllegalThreadStateException` if the client calls `startService(...)` more than once.

Comment: How would I avoid that?

Comment: It could start the Thread in `onCreate()`, which will only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

Services don't have their own thread, they run on the UI thread.  If you want it to run in parallel, you need to create a Thread.  So here you should create a Thread in your onStartCommand, and that thread should do whatever it is you want.

Comment: Will not I get second thread somewhere in memory when I re-enter my app since service is created in onCreate method, in MainActivity for example ?

Comment: No.  All activities and all services of an app exist on the same thread, unless one of them purposely spawn a thread.

Comment: Services can also be started in their own process, in which case their main thread will be distinct from your app's main thread.  Use the `android:process` attribute in the `service` tag in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Same way you'd log something at intervals in your activity: use a Handler.  Post a task that logs a message and re-posts itself to the same Handler using `postDelayed(...)`.  Cancel any pending execution in your activity's `onPause()` or your service's `onDestroy()`.

Note that there is almost never a good reason to explicitly create a Thread or use J2SE constructs like TimerTask in Android.  For heavyweight tasks, use AsyncTask.  For lightweight tasks, use Handlers.  In your case, creating a new Thread would be a ridiculously heavyweight solution for what you want to do.

Comment: My task is super heavyweight task and also has nothing to do with GUI at all. Im tryin to create a library, I just want someone to start my process and things should run forever, till process killed, then I start proccess automatically again.

Comment: Then I suggest asking about what you're actually doing instead of asking about doing something lightweight like posting a log message.  You may get entirely different answers.

Comment: But I think a super heavyweight task should be done in service? thread? background mode? etc. Am I wrong? and it should be compatible with any android app.

Comment: That all depends on what it is and what kind of lifecycle you want it to have.  I don't know what you mean by "background mode", and services and threads are not exclusive.  I think you need to be more clear about what you're trying to do.